# Request forbidden while accessing github api on node.js program

Tags: javascript, node.js, github

I'm trying to run this code but getting this error:

> Request forbidden by administrative rules, make sure your request has a User-Agent header

```
var https = require("https");
var username = 'jquery';

var options = {
host: 'api.github.com',
path: '/users/' + username + '/repos',
method: 'GET'
};

var request = https.request(options, function(response){
var body = '';
response.on("data", function(chunk){
    body += chunk.toString('utf8');
});

response.on("end", function(){
    console.log("Body: ", body);
    });
});

request.end();
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your `options` object does not have the `headers` option, describing the `user-agent`. Try this:

```
var options = {
    host: 'api.github.com',
    path: '/users/' + username + '/repos',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'user-agent': 'node.js'}
};
```

Comment: Now i am getting:-
"message": "Not Found","documentation_url":"http://developer.github.com/v3"

Comment: I've tried the same code you posted, and just included the headers. It worked fine for me. I'm running Node.js in a Windows 7 machine. But the "Not found" means that, at least, you're making de request.

Comment: Sorry my bad!!
I changed the username value to a username having zero repositroy
Thank You