# Request forbidden while accessing github api on php program

Tags: php, github-api

I'm reading the past of the [question (Request forbidden while accessing github api on node.js program)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21384582/6532249), but still does not solve the problem.

### PHP code

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.github.com/markdown/raw",
    CURLOPT_HEADER => [
        "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json",
        "Content-Type: text/plain",
        "User-Agent: mfmfneko"
    ],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "# Hello World!"
]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print($response);
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Check https://developer.github.com for other possible causes.
```

Comment: The response contains the solution (https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Try to change a User-Agent

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error message is self explanatory

Comment: @MaximTkach I tried these(mohuneko, page.mfnk.jp, mfmfneko/page.mfnk.jp), but the problem did not resolve.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Because they can not be solved by looking at the error message, I was asked. This post is detrimental to community?

Comment: it shows you spent no time trying to solve it yourself. Not even tried to google for error message

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I am already doing. It is **common sense**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake with the installation of headers.

> CURLOPT_HEADER    TRUE to include the header in the output.
>
> CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER    An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the
>   format array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')

They should be reported using the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

Try this code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.github.com/markdown/raw",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json",
            "Content-Type: text/plain",
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 YaBrowser/16.3.0.7146 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
        ],
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "# Hello World!"
    ]);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    print($response);
```

Response:

```
<h1>
<a id="user-content-hello-world" class="anchor" href="#hello-world" aria-hidden="true"><span aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a>Hello World!</h1>
```

[More details can be read here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)